# App should looks equals on all the screens

Tags: android, screen

I need my app to support all the screes variants and looks equals on every of them. What is the most simple way to provide this? I prefer to avoid writing great amount of layouts and styles as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992531/android-3-2-same-layout-for-all-screens). Just single layout for each screen. Is it possible?

Comment: Imagine that you have 480x800 .png asset of your future app. It should looks like this on 480x800 screen. Resize the image and you'll see **for example** 360x600 asset. The app should looks like this on 360x600 screen. And so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need my app to support all the screed variants and looks equals on every of them.

While possible, this is usually not the right answer. What works well on a phone-sized screen may be ineffective on a tablet (wasting space). And what works well on a phone or a tablet typically will not work well on a TV.

Your objective should be to *maximize usability* on the different screen sizes. It is possible that maximizing usability will wind up "looks equals on every of them", but that is not very likely.

> What is the most simple way to provide this?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract. That is akin to asking "what is the most simple way to paint", when we do not know if you are trying to paint a fingernail, a portrait, a house, or an airliner.

I encourage you to read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), then come back to StackOverflow with fresh, specific questions.

> I prefer to avoid writing great amount of layout and styles as here.

Just because there are lots of *directories* does not necessarily mean that there are lots of *layouts*. It could be that the majority of that app's layouts only needed 1-2 variants, but there were a couple that needed more. That being said, most apps do not need nearly so many options.

For example, [Google's iosched app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) (Google I|O conference schedule, map, etc.) has five layout resource sets:

- `layout/`
- `layout-land/`
- `layout-large-land-v11/`
- `layout-large-v11/`
- `layout-v11/`

As usual, one of every layout is in the `layout/` directory. `layout-land/` and `layout-large-land-v11/` only have one layout file apiece. `layout-large-v11/` has many, presumably to take advantage of the native action bar (`-v11`) and larger screen space.

Comment: Thank you. Can I for example set the button's width equals to 5% of screen width in layout?

Comment: @DotNETNinja: The way to do percentage-based layouts in Android is to use a `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` on the children in that `LinearLayout`. Here is a sample project demonstrating three buttons taking up 50%, 30%, and 20% of the screen: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Containers/LinearPercent

Comment: Great thanks! But what about percentage-based margins and paddings?

Comment: @DotNETNinja: Sorry, but that's not directly possible. You can fake precentage-based margins by using plain `<View>` elements as transparent spacers and applying the same `android:layout_weight` approach to them. And you are welcome to design your own `ViewGroup` that implements whatever rules you want. So if you want to create a `PercentageLayout` that does everything based on percentages, you are welcome to do so, though creating custom layout managers is a wee bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, so long as you keep the same theme across all of your apps, it doesn't matter if there are a few more or few less components showing on larger or smaller screen sizes. Android allows you to define a separate XML layout for different screen sizes anyway, so you could make use of that tool.